# How to get values between differents Shells/Displays - SWT

Tags: java, shell, swt

I'm beginner in SWT and I have a question about get values between differents Sheels/Displays.

I have 2 screens, one to sell and other to products' search.

When I open a sale's screen, and found the product in search's screen, I need send to sale's screen, the result of search.

The search's results are opened in a table, the row selected is loaded in sale's screen.

I don't know how to access sale's screen to load this values. Or through search's screen, to access fields in sale's screen and define values respective in fields the sale screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would register sale's screen as a selection listener on search's screen table. Once record is selected on search screen sale's screen will get notified and can handle selection event as needed. You can pass values from search screen to sale's screen in Event object.

Comment: Thank for your answer.

But, how did do this? You have an example?

Sorry, I'm beginner.